# Загрузка Bitmap на сервер

Tags: java, android

При помощи `Android Asynchronous Http Client` я загрузаю файлы на сервер:

```
try {
            params.put("name", name);
            params.put("uploaded_file", new File("..."));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.post("...", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {...}
```

создаю File на основе пути в памяти. Но как мне быть, если мне нужно отправить Bitmap. Можно сохранить его на карту и далле создать File. Но можно ли отправить сразу, без сохранения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перобразуйте `Bitmap` в массив байтов и отсылайте:

```
Bitmap botmap = ...;

ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, out);
byte[] myByteArray = out.toByteArray();

RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
params.put("uploaded_file", new ByteArrayInputStream(myByteArray), "image.png");
```